# how to use foreach with array_key_exists function

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to loop around an array of return values from a 'POST form' and to then place those values into a database.

the problem that I have is to determine the best way to loop around those values. I tried using the array_key_exists(). but it appears that this function only works with an If clause.

I am working in ZendFrameWork 1.

I enclose my code below and would really appreciate any help and advice.

```
 foreach(array_key_exists('id', $ReturnedPostvalues))

     $product = EP3D::getSource('EP3D/Products')->retrieve($productId);
     {  
      $product->quantity = $ReturnedPostvalues['quantity'];
      $product->price = $ReturnedPostvalues['price'];
      $product->rrp = $ReturnedPostvalues['rrp'];

      $product->save();
     }
    }
```

**the var_dumped  array values returned from the post**

```
 array(6) {
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(3) "222"
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "220"
    ["rrp"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["sampleId"]=>
    string(5) "42960"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["delete"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(7) {
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(4) "7777"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "2022"
    ["rrp"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["sampleId"]=>
    string(5) "42960"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["delete"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

I basically need to loop around this array and input the data into the database.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. The syntax of `foreach` is `foreach($array as $element)`. `array_key_exists` just returns true or false, not an array. And you don't have a `$element` iteration variable.

Comment: i have an array of returned values; each should have an Id. i want to be able to calulate how many arrays there are and then loop around the array and extract the information for each instance of that Id

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
foreach($ReturnedPostvalues as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists('id', $value)) {
        $product = EP3D::getSource('EP3D/Products')->retrieve($value['id']);
        $product->quantity = $value['quantity'];
        $product->price = $value['price'];
        $product->rrp = $value['rrp'];

        $product->save();
    }
}
```

You need to refresh your understanding of multi-dimensional arrays. Your problem is that you seemed to confuse accessing the top-level array and accessing the sub-arrays.

Comment: thank you for your kind advice Barmar. but less of the put down next time. we are all in the process of learning; nobody was born as an expert programmer. WE all had to start from somewhere

Comment: you want free assistance, sometimes you have to take the editorializing that comes along with it. This is basic competence, not an advanced technique that only experts would know. I joined SO to give and get help with tricky programming problems, but it seems like it's mostly teaching newbies basic programming techniques. Isn't that what schools are for?

Comment: i take your point; however this forumn is for programmers of all levels. the problem with putting people down is that you make others afraid to ask questions; it then becomes a bullying forumn as opposed to a place for programmers to exchange ideas and knowledge. No one has to right to bully others.

Comment: We all make mistakes: i am sure that if u looked back at your code from 3 years ago, you wont be happy with all of it. i made a valid mistake and appreciate you taking the time to point this out to me;  i however took accept ion to the put down.